# mapping the names of groups in a data-frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c','a','b','a'],'value':\
   [1,2,3,4,5,6],'value2':[7,8,9,10,11,12]})
```

I want to map the columns name to a new list for example:['G','H','F'], so I would get:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['G','H','F','G','H','G'],'value':\
   [1,2,3,4,5,6],'value2':[7,8,9,10,11,12]})
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in `pandas` method:

```
>>> df=pd.DataFrame({'name':['a','b','c','a','b','a'],'value':\
...    [1,2,3,4,5,6],'value2':[7,8,9,10,11,12]})
>>> df
  name  value  value2
0    a      1       7
1    b      2       8
2    c      3       9
3    a      4      10
4    b      5      11
5    a      6      12
>>> df.name.map({'a':'G','b':'H','c':'F'})
0    G
1    H
2    F
3    G
4    H
5    G
Name: name, dtype: object
>>> df['name'] = df.name.map({'a':'G','b':'H','c':'F'})
>>> df
  name  value  value2
0    G      1       7
1    H      2       8
2    F      3       9
3    G      4      10
4    H      5      11
5    G      6      12
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a dict:

```
mapping = {'a':'G', 'b':'H', 'c':'F'}
```

Then:

```
df['name'] = [mapping[item] for item in df['name']]
```